# Showing the inverse of an open and continuous function is also open

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Say we have an **open** set, defined as $ O ⊂ \mathbb{R}$, and $\forall \space x ∈  O \space \exists \space η > 0$ such that $(x − η, x + η) ⊂ O$.

I want to prove that if $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $O$ is open, then $f^{−1}(O) := \{x ∈ R : f(x) ∈ O\}$ is open.

But I am quite stumped as how to implement any of the given hypothesis.

Comment: I assume you're using the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity? Continuous functions are often _defined_ as functions for which $f^{-1}(O)$ is open for $O$ open.

Comment: Yes this is correct. In my class we have not been given this in the definition of a continuous function, however.

We are limited to the following definition:

Let $ f : A → \mathbb{R}$ and $c ∈ A$. $f$ is continuous at $c$ if,
for all $ε > 0$, there exists $δ > 0$ such that, whenever $x ∈ A$ and $|x − c| ≤ δ$, it follows $|f(x) − f(c)| ≤ ε$. $f$ is continuous on $B ⊂ A$ if it is continuous at each $c ∈ B$.

Comment: Hint: Suppose $O$ is open, and $x \in f^{-1}(O)$, then $f(x) \in O$, so $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $(f(x)-\epsilon,f(x)+\epsilon) \subset O$. Now choose $\delta > 0$ as given by your definition of continuity. What do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use that sets that are not open always have a limit point and that a continuous function sends a converging sequence to another converging sequence.